# Query to show label values in Grafana (using prometheus)

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I've a metric in below format:

```
code_smells_count{BLOCKER="176",CRITICAL="52",MAJOR="3784",instance="localhost:8080",job="my-metrics",domainId="65",domain="Sales",product="EmployeeSales",project_key="employee-sales"} 5000
```

I'm trying to write a query that will only display the value of `BLOCKER` in a gauge.

I tried:

```
sum(code_smells_count{product="[[product]]"})by (BLOCKER)
```

But this doesn't work, as it returns value of `code_smells_count{product="[[product]]"`, whereas I want only `BLOCKER="176"`

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

In Grafana, you can display the value of a tag with:

1. visualization: single stat
2. query: format should be `table`
3. visualization: should then display a drop-down menu of the tag to show (the name by default)

Comment: You can add the display of Gauge in SingleStat. I you use the Gauge widget, it will also display the value of the metric. If it doesn't fit your need, you can ask an evol to Grafana in order to get something similar to the table (to modify individual gauge)

Comment: This should be accepted answer. One thing to clarify, after step 2 you need to go to the visulizaiton tab in the same visulization. There you will find drop down for column values. Thanks !